# Configure Postman to Test Get New Access Token from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, postman, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

I am following instructions provided by Microsoft to set up Postman for testing an Azure AD B2C secured Wep API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=applications#register-a-web-application

Under the section **Use Postman to get a token and test the API**, I get to Step 4 where the documentation states:

> Postman opens a new window containing the Azure AD B2C tenant's
>   sign-in dialog. Sign in with an existing account (if one was created
>   testing the policies) or select Sign up now to create a new account.
>
> The Forgot your password? link is used to reset a forgotten password.

This does not happen.

I am using the Implicit Grant Type and my Auth URL appears as follows:

```
https://<myDomain>.b2clogin.com/<myDomain>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SIGNUP_SIGNIN&client_id=d4d84f32-1e57-4daf-b010-399bb2614e0d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

Scope is set to the following value:

```
https://<myDomain>.onmicrosoft.com/postman/user_impersonation openid offline_access
```

When I press the Postman **Request Token** button, the *SignIn / SignUp* User Flow (Policy) is interrupted with the following Error dialog stating:

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in. We track these errors
>   automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In
>   the meantime, please try again.

```
Correlation ID: c1b01e2d-84ce-446e-a9c2-f3a8617eb9f2
Timestamp: 2019-11-21 20:03:31Z
AADB2C90018: The client id 'd4d84f32-1e57-4daf-b010-399bb2614e0d,d4d84f32-1e57-4daf-b010-399bb2614e0d' specified in the request is not registered in tenant '<myDomain>.onmicrosoft.com'.
```

Taking this *client ID is not registered* error on face value, the problem would appear related to improper registration of the Application (Client) within Azure AD B2C.

However, I am able to successfully run this *SignIn / SignUp* User Flow from within Azure AD B2C; and to successfully register new Users using that Policy.

To be clear, my ASP.Net Core Web API is not being run at this stage.  I am simply trying to configure Postman to request a New Access Token from Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Which of the links you provided give you a page with anything about Postman? I'm trying to figure out how to get my Posty to obtain a token but I get stuck all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the document you provided and it works fine for me.

Based on your error message, it seems that you put your client id twice in the Client ID.

> AADB2C90018: The client id
>   '**d4d84f32-1e57-4daf-b010-399bb2614e0d,d4d84f32-1e57-4daf-b010-399bb2614e0d**'
>   specified in the request is not registered in tenant
>   '.onmicrosoft.com'.

Please check it.

Comment: Very good.  The problem was in the Auth URL, where I had included the full URL provided by Azure AD B2C for the purpose of testing my *SignUp / SignIn* Policy.  This resulted in duplication of the Client ID.


Only the following Auth URL value was required: 

`https://<myDomain>.b2clogin.com/<myDomain>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SIGNUP_SIGNIN`

Comment: This problem was mainly caused by my use of the full *Run user flow endpoint* URL (which Azure AD B2C generates for testing the *SignIn / SignUp* Policy) as the Postman Auth URL.

It was also necessary to preface the Scopes with the App ID URI in the Application Properties, described there as "optional".

The **Use Postman to get a token and test the API** section of the ASP.Net documentation describes a series of steps to **Register Postman as a web app**.  This step appears to be entirely unnecessary.  One simply needs to specify the Client ID for the Azure AD B2C Web API being tested.

Comment: I had similar issue, but my problem was to switch in Postman Client Authentication dropdown to "Send Credentials in body".